# Visual Studio - Autocomplete words for custom Objects / Libraries

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When typing code in Visual Studio 2015 it automatically gives me alternatives on what I can do with my code:

[image: Autocomplete]

I was wondering if there is a way to enable autocomplete on imported Objects / Libraries (.dll) files?

I am using IBM 3270 and have imported all of the libraries and added them as references to my project, but I still don't get any alternatives.

Here is an example of the code and what I believe it should do:

```
' The Imports are already referenced to the project.
' I have added them here to visually display that I am using the libraries.

Imports AutConnListTypeLibrary
Imports AutConnMgrTypeLibrary
Imports AutOIATypeLibrary
Imports AutPSTypeLibrary
Imports AutSystemTypeLibrary

Public Class IBM3270

    Public Shared autECLConnList As Object
    autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")

    autECLConnList. ' <- I believe that I should get autocomplete words here, but I don't. 
    ' Some of the alternatives that should pop up are:
    ' autECLConnList.Count
    ' autECLConnList.Refresh

End Class
```

[Link to IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_6.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access08.htm)

**EDIT:** I have rewritten the code and the Autocomplete words appears, but I can't figure out how I can execute it now. Previously I used `CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")` to access the object.

Here is what I have:

```
Imports AutConnListTypeLibrary

Public Class IBM3270
Implements AutConnList

Default Public ReadOnly Property ConnInfo(Index As Object) As Object Implements IAutConnList.ConnInfo
    Get
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements IAutConnList.Count
    Get
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub Refresh() Implements IAutConnList.Refresh
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Test() ' Here is where I am stuck.
    Dim autECLConnList As AutConnList ' I believe I can't reference AutConnList. ("PCOMM.autECLConnList") should probably be added someplace.
    autECLConnList.Refresh
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You don't get anything there because the type of `autECLConnList` is type `Object`.  If you want to be prompted with members of a specific type then your variable has to be that type.  You need to either cast as that type or use a constructor instead of `CreateObject`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will be looking into that! :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have rewritten the code and the Autocomplete words appears, but I can't figure out how I can execute it now. Nothing happens and I believe it is because I have implemented it incorrectly. I have updated the my post with the new code. It starts from "Edit:". Help would be much appreciated. Thank you Jmcilhinney.

Comment: You are declaring a variable but you're not creating an object. You're not doing what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, it's all very new to me. I am trying to wrap my head around it. I'll have to do some more reading. Thanks!

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have solved it now! `Dim autECLConnList As AutConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")` works!